# How to read Folder name from a selected path into a text box using C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read the folder name from a particular path into a text box using C# web application. When I used `ASP:FileUpload` control, I am able to get only the name of the selected file, not the full path. As I am working on it for the first time, I am not able to get the details exactly. Please, anyone help me get the folder or subfolder name from the selected path.

Comment: Please share the code you're using to get the file name

Comment: What do you mean with `I want to read the folder name from a particular path into a text box`?

Comment: A file input element *should* only provide the file, not any other information about the user's file system.  (*[looking at you, IE]*)  What are you trying to do that's failing?

Comment: By using Fileupload control can we get the full path of the selected file.

Comment: @samyu: No.  Because the posted information does not (*should* not) contain more than just the file itself, to include its name and content type.  *Some* browsers may provide the full path as the file name.  But most don't.  And none should.  The more important question is why you think you *need* this information.  We don't know what actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: you can use `string dirName = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;` from `System.IO`

Comment: I am trying to get a folder name into a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file)).ToArray(); By using this code i am able to get all the directory names in the particular path.

Answer (score 0):

You can get full name of the file, then get the name of the directory:

```
string fileFullPath = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
string directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullPath);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Hi, Iam using the below code  [STAThreadAttribute]
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {  }  protected void Btnclk(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   string directory; FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new folderBrowserDialog(); if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {  directory = fbd.SelectedPath;
                load.Text = directory;
            }I am getting exception like "An exception of type System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code".  Please help to solve it.

Comment: Are you getting the exception in line  load.Text = directory  ?

Comment: I am getting the exception in the below line "if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)"

Comment: take a look this this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636878/opening-files-in-a-form-threadstateexception-was-unhandled

Comment: @Eugene, Even after using [STATread] attribute it is giving the same exception.

Comment: Wait a moment, are you trying to run ShowDialog() in web application ???

Comment: Yes @Eugene, I am using in web application, but i have added the System.Windows.Forms dll.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. You cannot run ShowDialog() from web application